# How do I execute a java method/function inside jmeter's __groovy() function?

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter

I'm new to jmeter. I have a java function whose output needs to be passed to Http Request body. I'm using jmeter's groovy() function for the same. I created a jar file and placed it in the lib folder, and restarted jmeter. Then, when I try to make an instance of the class and execute a method, I'm not able to get the value returned by the function. How do I execute a java snippet/function inside jmeter's groovy() function.

Request Body :-

```
  "key": "${__groovy(TestEncryption encryption = new TestEncryption(); encryption.encrypt();)}"
```

I don't see any response at all after the API call.

Comment: Show what you tried and the error you got

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be something like:

```
 ${__groovy(new your.package.your.Class().yourFunction(param1\, param2),)}
```

for example calling [Random.nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) will look like:

```
${__groovy(new java.util.Random().nextInt(10),)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JMeter: Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: The java function is getting executed but the value is not being replaced in the request body.